# Decrypt results in NULL value for migrated database

Tags: sql-server, database-migration

After migrating a SQL Server on VM to SQL Server managed instance, the decryption is not working. It returns null values.

I find it weird when decrypting a column from a baked up database and restoring it to another database.

Here's the scenario:

- `Server1` has `Database1`
- `Database1` has `Table1` with one column which is encrypted -- `user code`
- Encryption and decryption in this `Database1` is perfectly fine. Records are encrypted and can be decrypted too.

Now, I tried to backup this `Database1` and restore it to a SQL Server managed Instance. I tried decrypting the column using the same command to decrypt in `Database1`, however, it returns a NULL value

Need help on this topic.

Comment: Where is the encryption key stored, in which database? What actual code are you using?

Comment: if it were possible to just simply decrypt database from backup, there would be no point to encryption